# Android How to Decode quoted-printable string

Tags: android, string, replace, quoted-printable

I can't find any type of method to decode quoted-printable text into string.
If I have a message like this:

```
       =20
       =20
       =20
       =20
        Google Cloud Platform & APIs

=C8 disponibile la tua fattura mensile di Google Cloud Platform & APIs. Puo=
i =20
trovare in allegato il documento PDF in fondo a questa email.


------=_Part_0_631827638716.12983498136
Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=file1.puu
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=file1.puu

AAEC
------=_Part_0_631827638716.12983498136
```

How is it possible to extract only the message part and decode it?
Thanks in advance